# pandas, comparison within lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a function which returns the names of the pandas dataframe columns which have a number of unique values <= 100:

```
cols_unique = list(df[cols].loc[:, df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.nunique()) <= 100])
```

I would like to change this to return the column names in which the number of unique values are <= 50% of the total number of values, my attempt:

```
cols_unique = list(df[cols].loc[:, df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.nunique() <= x.count()/2]))
```

But this doesn't work.

How does one do a comparison within a lambda function?

Comment: you really need a working example with a small dataframe to illustrate your question better.

Comment: @PaulH That's indeed true which are seeing many of the time missing :-)

Comment: try `cols_unique = list(df[cols].loc[:, df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.nunique() <= len(df)//2]))` instead ?

Comment: Thanks @Chris A but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you might try:

```
cols_unique = list(df[cols].loc[:, df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.nunique() <= len(df) / 2)])
```

If you're open to an alternative that doesn't use a `lambda` function, you could try:

```
 list(cols[df[cols].nunique().le(len(df) // 2)])
```

Comment: Thanks, the syntax of these work although as it turns out all my columns meet the criteria so I've tested with a lower threshold (<= 10%) and it works. I should have spotted that x.count() is the same as len(df) - doh!